# spring boot custom error pages do not render when deployed on server

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, custom-error-pages

As per documentation I have written a custom error page for spring boot app 404.html and placed this file in src/main/resources/public/error/404.html. Also my application.properties file contains 'server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false'. Now on localhost this 404.html gets rendered, but when deployed on server this page does not render and instead tomcat HTTP 404 error page gets displayed. Can anyone suggest how I can solve this.

PS : The files 404.html, 404.css get bundled up in WEB-INF folder in war deployed on server.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem before, i just added these configuration in my application.properties file

```
# Spring
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.resources.add-mappings=false
```

---

**note: Use this config. on application that is deployed on server. This will code will make your application ignore resources when used on spring boot locally (embedded tomcat)**

Comment: okay, thanks! have you added any controller to handle this exception or only custom error html files in src/main/resources/public/error/404.html?

Comment: I have a class that has @controlleradvice to handle exceptions globally. https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring